# Windows 10 - How to auto switch to WIFI if Ethernet stops working?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, broadband

I need to use Ethernet most of the time, however my broadband goes down relatively often. When the broadband (connected via Ethernet) stops working I want it to automatically use WIFI (I have a 4G router). Right now it only switches to WIFI when I physically disconnect the Ethernet plug, if the broadband stops working then it doesn't switch to WIFI at all,  I have to physically unplug the Ethernet cable for it to switch to WIFI.

Comment: Explore doing this with PowerShell commands manually first step-by-step and turn that work into a PS script. If you can do it via PowerShell, you can automate easily. Quick advice if you want to avoid the physical component in your situation entirely potentially. Perhaps disabling the Ethernet interface via PowerShell will be enough to make it switch when something occurs you can use as a trigger. `netsh int set int "$IntName" admin=disable` for the correct interface name on your system. Wrap it all into some conditional or event triggered action that occurs with the problem.

Comment: What happens when Ethernet goes down, what are the symptoms?

Comment: Thank you, i created a powershell script to auto change the interface metric of Ethernet when ping fails with it, it auto connects back when ping starts working

Comment: You should post the script here so that it helps others in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The default connection metrics in Windows are such that switching takes place quickly from Ethernet to Wireless if there is no Ethernet connection. Since the Ether is likely plugged into a router or Modem/Router, there actually is a connection - just no Internet in the above case.

Therefore, truly easiest and best to unplug Ethernet and let it switch. It will.

If you lose your Wireless, then you must plug in the Ethernet cable, so it is very near the same action.